# Meteor iron-route onBeforeAction

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have this simple Iron-router route in my Meteor application which I use whenever any user need to logout of the app, although whenever I call this route I get the following error. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong/ missing here? Thanks

On a minor note, Meteor.logout doesn't return any error

```
Router.route('/logout', function(){
  Meteor.logout(function(err){
      if(err){
        console.log('Error Logging out: '+ err);
      }
      this.redirect('home');
  });
});
```

Error:

```
 Route dispatch never rendered. Did you forget to call this.next() in an onBeforeAction?

Exception in delivering result of invoking 'logout': TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at http://localhost:3000/both/router/routes.js?8871acf5e06150f7af89862f68c245a05fe13db8:110:12
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/accounts-base.js?7c29db5c21a76726509bb6bb2a68a2b4b1ecf657:674:19
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scope in Meteor.logout callback is not the same scope as in Router.route callback. That's why you need to assign Router.route's scope to variable `self` and then use it inside Meteor.logout callback.

```
Router.route('/logout', function(){
  var self = this;
  Meteor.logout(function(err){
      if(err){
        console.log('Error Logging out: '+ err);
      }
      self.redirect('home');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Kuba, appreciate it